# Which ANTLR product do I choose?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ide, antlr

I am confused, please do help me out. According to this tutorial, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ecl-commplgin1/index.html, the first thing I need to do is create a parser and lexer. Okay, I've decided to use ANTLR. Now I've checked ANTLR on the net.. But which kind of ANTLR should I use? ANTLR Works / ANTLR V3 / ANTLR V4? I would like to build an editor after this phase, so I hope the generated parser / lexer / etc can be integrated smoothly with it. What I'm trying to do here actually is create an IDE for my language that can plug-in into Eclipse. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you want to do Eclipse editors for the language you should look at [Eclipse Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR (ANother Tool for Language Recognition) is a tool for generating recognizer of various kinds. There are currently 2 versions out there: v4, the latest one, and v3 the previous one which is still in wide use because of the needed runtimes for different language targets (many haven't been ported to v4 yet).

ANTLR Works is a standalone IDE for developing ANTLR recognizers. There are other tools like Eclipse plugins, a VS plugin etc.

If you are going with Eclipse it sounds natural to me to use the Eclipse plugin for developing the parser for your IDE. You should probably first play a bit with other applications, test parser etc. to get an idea how this works.